# Creating a list within linQ query

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have the following DTO:

```
public class ContinentScopeDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long? ContinentId { get; set; }
    public List<CountryScopeDto> CountriessPairList { get; set; }
}
```

The CountryScopeDto model is as follows:

```
public class CountryScopeDto
{
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public long? CountryId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to select the continent name and id and its list of related countries.

My linq query is as follows:

```
 var query = (from branch in this.DataAccess.GetOperations<PA_BRANCHES>().FindAll(item => silosBranch.Contains(item.Id))
                     join country in this.DataAccess.GetOperations<PA_LIST_OF_COUNTRIES>().FindAll()
                     on branch.COU_N_ID equals country.Id
                     join countryTrad in this.DataAccess.GetOperations<PA_LIST_OF_COUNTRIES_TRAD>().FindAll(item => item.LANG_CH_TAG.Equals(userlang))
                     on country.Id equals countryTrad.COU_N_ID
                     join continentTrad in this.DataAccess.GetOperations<PA_LIST_OF_CONTINENTS_TRAD>().FindAll(item => item.LANG_CH_TAG.Equals(userlang))
                     on country.CONT_N_ID equals continentTrad.CONT_N_ID
                     select new ContinentScopeDto
                     {
                         Name = continentTrad.TONT_CH_LABEL,
                         ContinentId = continentTrad.CONT_N_ID,
                         CountriessPairList = new List<CountryScopeDto>
                         {

                         }
                     }

            );
```

Here I don't know how to create a list of the countries of that continent.

My query should return a list of continents with their countries.

Any help pls.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-populate-object-collections-from-multiple-sources-linq

Go through the above link, you will get it to know how the list creating in linq.